# Is it possible to use my css in jquery

Tags: jquery

I got jquery script that I can use for my site and it works as intended. The only problem is that the fonts and size used by this jquery don't even look the same with the rest of the page. 
According to the site where I got that jquery, in order for the jquery to work I have to include these links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

How can I incorporate or change the css to my own css so the jquery fonts can look the same with the rest of the fonts in my site? for example, the font in jquery auto complete looks so much bigger than the rest of the font in the page

Comment: So set the size of the text in your CSS....

Answer (score -1):

Put your desired font property declaration.

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but I don't know jquery at all. I just copied and pasted the example I found into my form. Do I have to put <style> </style> and then body { .... }?

Comment: <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
    
      'abc','abd','abe','abf','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx','yz'
 
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script> this is the autocomplete jquery example, I need to change the font so it will look like my css
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>

Comment: Style tag will work. But do you have multiple HTML with a single CSS file? In that case add this to your CSS file, which is better practice. You can also do this:.ui-widget {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

Comment: Shi, thank you! I added: :.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; } in my css and it works!